# Set permissions to folder on Azure Webservices (ASp.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ASP.NET  app

I host it on Azure using Web App Service

I have `uploads` folder where I write videos.

Videos writes well, but when I try to read it and display on View I have this error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I think error in permissions.

I connect to website using IIS Manager

But I don't understood how get read/write property to `uploads`  folder.

Here is my website structure

[image]

How I can set permissions on Web App Services?

Comment: I think this could be application pool user permission issue..provide permission to application pool user with full control or read permission

Comment: How I can do this? @BharatPatidar